# Error when trying to delete data from table with LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

In LINQ I am trying to write a query that will, once a button is clicked, delete a record from a database table, namely "Amendments_Awaiting_Approval".  This row will be found and deleted based on the value entered in a text box.  So far I have this: ' Your input string

```
Dim parseRef As String = txtReferenceCode.Text

'Convert string to integer value '
Dim deleteRecord As Integer = Integer.Parse(parseRef)

' Query the database for the rows to be deleted. '
Dim deleteModuleChanges = _
    From amendments In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals _
    Where amendments.Amendments_ID = deleteRecord _
    Select amendments

For Each amendment As Amendments_Awaiting_Approval In deleteModuleChanges()
    db.OrderDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(detail)
Next
```

This segment is not working.  The page won't even load and when I mouse over the deleteModuleChanges() section I get the error "Overload resolution failed because no accessible ElementAtOrDefault accepts this number of arguments"

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the parentheses from `deleteModuleChanges()`:  `For Each amendment As Amendments_Awaiting_Approval In deleteModuleChages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deleteModuleChanges` is `IEnumerable`, so when you add `()` to it VB.NET compiler tries to fire `ElementAtOrDefault` extension method on that collection, what can't be done without a parameter. Try that one:

```
For Each amendment As Amendments_Awaiting_Approval In deleteModuleChanges
    db.OrderDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(detail)
Next
```

However, I don't know why you're iterating over `amendment`, but delete `detail`. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

And of course, you have to submit changes:

```
db.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: +1 for explaining *why* the parentheses was causing the problem :)

Comment: That's one of the most weird VB.NET behavior I've ever seen :)

Comment: I concur with the +1 for explanation.  No, it was a typo that I had over looked.  It was a code segment I hadn't finished adjusting yet.